# What is Presence?

Tags: amplifier, keyboard

I got an Ibanez amplifier for my keyboard and there is a dial called 'presence'.   What does it do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[A presence control boosts the upper mid-range frequencies. Thus by increasing the presence with the presence control, the sounds of voices and such instruments seem more "present".](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Presence_%28amplification%29)

Comment: This article is a stub that doesn't explain presence very well. Also, answers that are just a link [are discouraged on SE sites](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7515/why-is-linking-bad/7519#7519).

Answer (score 3):

Presence boosts high frequencies. I believe the idea behind it is that you will be more 'present' whilst soloing.

Comment: Can you explain more exactly?

Comment: I was just about to link to that wiki article. I think that explains it pretty well.

Comment: Yeah it says basically the same thing you said thanks.